# Ubuntu unattended upgrades to run at a certain time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, upgrade

I'm trying to work out the best way to run unattended upgrades every Thursday at 3am but can only see a way to run this weekly but not a given time.

I thought of one way would be to have a script that is called by cron on Thursday at 3am

The below script would work just for security updates

```
#!/bin/sh
sh -c 'grep precise-security /etc/apt/sources.list > /etc/apt/secsrc.list'
sh -c 'apt-get -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="secsrc.list" \
-o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" update && \
apt-get --assume-yes upgrade'
```

Any thoughts on another way?

Comment: Cron is specifically intended for running things unattended at certain times on certain days.  Is there any reason not to use it, as you clearly have considered?

Comment: I think I must be missing something as I can't see how to use unattended upgrades with cron other then using a script like above, thanks

Comment: So use the script above!  Seriously, if it works, and it's using standard infrastructure like `cron`, it's probably fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What wrong with doing it this way? If you just add a cron rule `0 3 * * Thu USERNAME SCRIPT`  it should work fine.

Comment: So by using the script above but changing it to include updates ?

Comment: If you run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade --assume-yes` it should install whatever upgrades you have pending.

Answer (score 0):

try using cron-apt, here is my config:

```
APTCOMMAND=/usr/bin/aptitude # or /usr/bin/apt-get
MAILON="always"
SYSLOGON="upgrade"
MAILTO="ruslanas.gzibovskis@ittc.vu.lt"
OPTIONS="-o quiet=2"
```

and actions.d/3-download i modified:

```
autoclean -y
dist-upgrade -d -y -o APT::Get::Show-Upgraded=true
upgrade -y -o APT::Install-Recommends=false -o APT::Install-Suggests=false
dist-upgrade -y -o APT::Install-Recommends=false -o APT::Install-Suggests=false
clean
```

hope that will help ;)